# How to make image stick to the bottom of section on all device heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make this image to be on the bottom of this section (section 18) of one page website (which has 21 section) for all devices heights using jQuery.

I made it by using `position: absolute` etc. but just on my screen size. When I check that on other devices that have different heights, it's not stuck to the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Use `position: fixed; bottom: 0`

Comment: With position absolute, the image will stay at the bottom of the section on every device. Make sure you set `position:relative` to that section. If you want the image to be at the bottom of the section and at the bottom of the screen in the same time, then the only way that would make sense is if the section has the same height of the screen, you can use viewport units for that. in this case `100vh` height

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```css
.imagebottom{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et urna enim. Nunc ac ligula sed augue vehicula consectetur a quis justo. Pellentesque viverra nisi turpis, convallis interdum ex lobortis nec. Fusce eget sem pellentesque, sagittis metus sed, euismod diam. Donec pharetra sed neque eget eleifend. Sed varius ultricies orci, vel volutpat massa hendrerit vel. Curabitur euismod tempor porta. Nulla at ligula id quam elementum vulputate. Nullam blandit sem in congue tincidunt. Etiam at vehicula ante. Suspendisse nec pulvinar libero. Suspendisse potenti. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Aenean dignissim neque et arcu convallis dictum ac in lectus. Etiam maximus felis eget arcu maximus, non lacinia massa scelerisque. In mollis eros vel ex blandit, eget vestibulum quam facilisis. Sed vulputate porta pharetra. Quisque id sapien nec urna iaculis porttitor sit amet in nibh. Integer vel nisl sit amet arcu dictum auctor. Maecenas condimentum nulla vel maximus ullamcorper. Morbi malesuada, lacus non pellentesque condimentum, magna odio accumsan nisi, nec mollis nunc nibh at orci. Nulla venenatis ante quis eros fermentum, eget maximus risus ornare. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Pellentesque commodo neque et neque ultricies venenatis. Morbi justo ligula, sodales a molestie a, elementum ac quam. Sed a dui ac lacus mattis vestibulum id non ante. Phasellus efficitur vehicula pellentesque. Phasellus id porta risus, eget posuere libero. Praesent tristique tortor vel nunc aliquam, lacinia finibus augue mollis. Ut condimentum sollicitudin metus, id lacinia odio cursus ut. Integer iaculis tempor nulla vel posuere.

Etiam non erat velit. Mauris ac sodales orci. Etiam posuere quam et gravida cursus. Mauris lacinia auctor ipsum in vehicula. Sed quis dictum enim. Ut eleifend erat sit amet est egestas, nec consequat orci laoreet. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam egestas quam ut augue efficitur, in sagittis quam tempor. Suspendisse sagittis blandit elit at pretium. Ut turpis dolor, lacinia sit amet ex id, ultricies pretium dui. Pellentesque posuere nec elit nec sagittis. Ut ut efficitur nisl. Nam placerat arcu eros, a facilisis massa elementum et. Maecenas et gravida nunc.

Vestibulum metus urna, placerat ac iaculis at, blandit vitae ante. Ut porta bibendum massa, varius rhoncus odio. Proin libero tortor, tincidunt sit amet mi nec, aliquam fermentum augue. Praesent sed efficitur metus. Phasellus accumsan, velit vel ornare auctor, nisi diam condimentum risus, sit amet ultricies est lacus vitae lectus. Etiam mattis lectus eu nunc lobortis efficitur. Nunc dui mauris, iaculis vitae dignissim in, ullamcorper vel odio. Sed gravida enim eu ex scelerisque, ut sagittis lacus ullamcorper. Fusce aliquet maximus lorem laoreet posuere. Nam tristique nisi ullamcorper felis tempus pulvinar.
</div>
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et urna enim. Nunc ac ligula sed augue vehicula consectetur a quis justo. Pellentesque viverra nisi turpis, convallis interdum ex lobortis nec. Fusce eget sem pellentesque, sagittis metus sed, euismod diam. Donec pharetra sed neque eget eleifend. Sed varius ultricies orci, vel volutpat massa hendrerit vel. Curabitur euismod tempor porta. Nulla at ligula id quam elementum vulputate. Nullam blandit sem in congue tincidunt. Etiam at vehicula ante. Suspendisse nec pulvinar libero. Suspendisse potenti. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Aenean dignissim neque et arcu convallis dictum ac in lectus. Etiam maximus felis eget arcu maximus, non lacinia massa scelerisque. In mollis eros vel ex blandit, eget vestibulum quam facilisis. Sed vulputate porta pharetra. Quisque id sapien nec urna iaculis porttitor sit amet in nibh. Integer vel nisl sit amet arcu dictum auctor. Maecenas condimentum nulla vel maximus ullamcorper. Morbi malesuada, lacus non pellentesque condimentum, magna odio accumsan nisi, nec mollis nunc nibh at orci. Nulla venenatis ante quis eros fermentum, eget maximus risus ornare. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Pellentesque commodo neque et neque ultricies venenatis. Morbi justo ligula, sodales a molestie a, elementum ac quam. Sed a dui ac lacus mattis vestibulum id non ante. Phasellus efficitur vehicula pellentesque. Phasellus id porta risus, eget posuere libero. Praesent tristique tortor vel nunc aliquam, lacinia finibus augue mollis. Ut condimentum sollicitudin metus, id lacinia odio cursus ut. Integer iaculis tempor nulla vel posuere.

Etiam non erat velit. Mauris ac sodales orci. Etiam posuere quam et gravida cursus. Mauris lacinia auctor ipsum in vehicula. Sed quis dictum enim. Ut eleifend erat sit amet est egestas, nec consequat orci laoreet. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam egestas quam ut augue efficitur, in sagittis quam tempor. Suspendisse sagittis blandit elit at pretium. Ut turpis dolor, lacinia sit amet ex id, ultricies pretium dui. Pellentesque posuere nec elit nec sagittis. Ut ut efficitur nisl. Nam placerat arcu eros, a facilisis massa elementum et. Maecenas et gravida nunc.

Vestibulum metus urna, placerat ac iaculis at, blandit vitae ante. Ut porta bibendum massa, varius rhoncus odio. Proin libero tortor, tincidunt sit amet mi nec, aliquam fermentum augue. Praesent sed efficitur metus. Phasellus accumsan, velit vel ornare auctor, nisi diam condimentum risus, sit amet ultricies est lacus vitae lectus. Etiam mattis lectus eu nunc lobortis efficitur. Nunc dui mauris, iaculis vitae dignissim in, ullamcorper vel odio. Sed gravida enim eu ex scelerisque, ut sagittis lacus ullamcorper. Fusce aliquet maximus lorem laoreet posuere. Nam tristique nisi ullamcorper felis tempus pulvinar.
</div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/igp05.png" class="imagebottom"/>
```

Comment: I have one page website with 21 sections.. It cant be fixed, I need it to be stacked to the just section 18..

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: sticky` instead of `position: fixed`. A sticky element always sticks to its nearest ancestor element which in your case is the 18th section of your website.

```css
.imagebottom{
    position: sticky;
    bottom:0px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2>Section 17</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et urna enim. Nunc ac ligula sed augue vehicula consectetur a quis justo. Pellentesque viverra nisi turpis, convallis interdum ex lobortis nec. Fusce eget sem pellentesque, sagittis metus sed, euismod diam. Donec pharetra sed neque eget eleifend. Sed varius ultricies orci, vel volutpat massa hendrerit vel. Curabitur euismod tempor porta. Nulla at ligula id quam elementum vulputate. Nullam blandit sem in congue tincidunt. Etiam at vehicula ante. Suspendisse nec pulvinar libero. Suspendisse potenti. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Aenean dignissim neque et arcu convallis dictum ac in lectus. Etiam maximus felis eget arcu maximus, non lacinia massa scelerisque. In mollis eros vel ex blandit, eget vestibulum quam facilisis. Sed vulputate porta pharetra. Quisque id sapien nec urna iaculis porttitor sit amet in nibh. Integer vel nisl sit amet arcu dictum auctor. Maecenas condimentum nulla vel maximus ullamcorper. Morbi malesuada, lacus non pellentesque condimentum, magna odio accumsan nisi, nec mollis nunc nibh at orci. Nulla venenatis ante quis eros fermentum, eget maximus risus ornare. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Pellentesque commodo neque et neque ultricies venenatis. Morbi justo ligula, sodales a molestie a, elementum ac quam. Sed a dui ac lacus mattis vestibulum id non ante. Phasellus efficitur vehicula pellentesque. Phasellus id porta risus, eget posuere libero. Praesent tristique tortor vel nunc aliquam, lacinia finibus augue mollis. Ut condimentum sollicitudin metus, id lacinia odio cursus ut. Integer iaculis tempor nulla vel posuere.

Etiam non erat velit. Mauris ac sodales orci. Etiam posuere quam et gravida cursus. Mauris lacinia auctor ipsum in vehicula. Sed quis dictum enim. Ut eleifend erat sit amet est egestas, nec consequat orci laoreet. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam egestas quam ut augue efficitur, in sagittis quam tempor. Suspendisse sagittis blandit elit at pretium. Ut turpis dolor, lacinia sit amet ex id, ultricies pretium dui. Pellentesque posuere nec elit nec sagittis. Ut ut efficitur nisl. Nam placerat arcu eros, a facilisis massa elementum et. Maecenas et gravida nunc.

Vestibulum metus urna, placerat ac iaculis at, blandit vitae ante. Ut porta bibendum massa, varius rhoncus odio. Proin libero tortor, tincidunt sit amet mi nec, aliquam fermentum augue. Praesent sed efficitur metus. Phasellus accumsan, velit vel ornare auctor, nisi diam condimentum risus, sit amet ultricies est lacus vitae lectus. Etiam mattis lectus eu nunc lobortis efficitur. Nunc dui mauris, iaculis vitae dignissim in, ullamcorper vel odio. Sed gravida enim eu ex scelerisque, ut sagittis lacus ullamcorper. Fusce aliquet maximus lorem laoreet posuere. Nam tristique nisi ullamcorper felis tempus pulvinar.
</div>
<br />
<hr />
<br />
<div>
<h2>Section 18</h2>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et urna enim. Nunc ac ligula sed augue vehicula consectetur a quis justo. Pellentesque viverra nisi turpis, convallis interdum ex lobortis nec. Fusce eget sem pellentesque, sagittis metus sed, euismod diam. Donec pharetra sed neque eget eleifend. Sed varius ultricies orci, vel volutpat massa hendrerit vel. Curabitur euismod tempor porta. Nulla at ligula id quam elementum vulputate. Nullam blandit sem in congue tincidunt. Etiam at vehicula ante. Suspendisse nec pulvinar libero. Suspendisse potenti. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Aenean dignissim neque et arcu convallis dictum ac in lectus. Etiam maximus felis eget arcu maximus, non lacinia massa scelerisque. In mollis eros vel ex blandit, eget vestibulum quam facilisis. Sed vulputate porta pharetra. Quisque id sapien nec urna iaculis porttitor sit amet in nibh. Integer vel nisl sit amet arcu dictum auctor. Maecenas condimentum nulla vel maximus ullamcorper. Morbi malesuada, lacus non pellentesque condimentum, magna odio accumsan nisi, nec mollis nunc nibh at orci. Nulla venenatis ante quis eros fermentum, eget maximus risus ornare. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Pellentesque commodo neque et neque ultricies venenatis. Morbi justo ligula, sodales a molestie a, elementum ac quam. Sed a dui ac lacus mattis vestibulum id non ante. Phasellus efficitur vehicula pellentesque. Phasellus id porta risus, eget posuere libero. Praesent tristique tortor vel nunc aliquam, lacinia finibus augue mollis. Ut condimentum sollicitudin metus, id lacinia odio cursus ut. Integer iaculis tempor nulla vel posuere.

Etiam non erat velit. Mauris ac sodales orci. Etiam posuere quam et gravida cursus. Mauris lacinia auctor ipsum in vehicula. Sed quis dictum enim. Ut eleifend erat sit amet est egestas, nec consequat orci laoreet. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam egestas quam ut augue efficitur, in sagittis quam tempor. Suspendisse sagittis blandit elit at pretium. Ut turpis dolor, lacinia sit amet ex id, ultricies pretium dui. Pellentesque posuere nec elit nec sagittis. Ut ut efficitur nisl. Nam placerat arcu eros, a facilisis massa elementum et. Maecenas et gravida nunc.

Vestibulum metus urna, placerat ac iaculis at, blandit vitae ante. Ut porta bibendum massa, varius rhoncus odio. Proin libero tortor, tincidunt sit amet mi nec, aliquam fermentum augue. Praesent sed efficitur metus. Phasellus accumsan, velit vel ornare auctor, nisi diam condimentum risus, sit amet ultricies est lacus vitae lectus. Etiam mattis lectus eu nunc lobortis efficitur. Nunc dui mauris, iaculis vitae dignissim in, ullamcorper vel odio. Sed gravida enim eu ex scelerisque, ut sagittis lacus ullamcorper. Fusce aliquet maximus lorem laoreet posuere. Nam tristique nisi ullamcorper felis tempus pulvinar.
</p>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/igp05.png" class="imagebottom"/>
</div>
<br />
<hr />
<br />
<div>
<h2>Section 19</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et urna enim. Nunc ac ligula sed augue vehicula consectetur a quis justo. Pellentesque viverra nisi turpis, convallis interdum ex lobortis nec. Fusce eget sem pellentesque, sagittis metus sed, euismod diam. Donec pharetra sed neque eget eleifend. Sed varius ultricies orci, vel volutpat massa hendrerit vel. Curabitur euismod tempor porta. Nulla at ligula id quam elementum vulputate. Nullam blandit sem in congue tincidunt. Etiam at vehicula ante. Suspendisse nec pulvinar libero. Suspendisse potenti. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Aenean dignissim neque et arcu convallis dictum ac in lectus. Etiam maximus felis eget arcu maximus, non lacinia massa scelerisque. In mollis eros vel ex blandit, eget vestibulum quam facilisis. Sed vulputate porta pharetra. Quisque id sapien nec urna iaculis porttitor sit amet in nibh. Integer vel nisl sit amet arcu dictum auctor. Maecenas condimentum nulla vel maximus ullamcorper. Morbi malesuada, lacus non pellentesque condimentum, magna odio accumsan nisi, nec mollis nunc nibh at orci. Nulla venenatis ante quis eros fermentum, eget maximus risus ornare. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Pellentesque commodo neque et neque ultricies venenatis. Morbi justo ligula, sodales a molestie a, elementum ac quam. Sed a dui ac lacus mattis vestibulum id non ante. Phasellus efficitur vehicula pellentesque. Phasellus id porta risus, eget posuere libero. Praesent tristique tortor vel nunc aliquam, lacinia finibus augue mollis. Ut condimentum sollicitudin metus, id lacinia odio cursus ut. Integer iaculis tempor nulla vel posuere.

Etiam non erat velit. Mauris ac sodales orci. Etiam posuere quam et gravida cursus. Mauris lacinia auctor ipsum in vehicula. Sed quis dictum enim. Ut eleifend erat sit amet est egestas, nec consequat orci laoreet. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam egestas quam ut augue efficitur, in sagittis quam tempor. Suspendisse sagittis blandit elit at pretium. Ut turpis dolor, lacinia sit amet ex id, ultricies pretium dui. Pellentesque posuere nec elit nec sagittis. Ut ut efficitur nisl. Nam placerat arcu eros, a facilisis massa elementum et. Maecenas et gravida nunc.

Vestibulum metus urna, placerat ac iaculis at, blandit vitae ante. Ut porta bibendum massa, varius rhoncus odio. Proin libero tortor, tincidunt sit amet mi nec, aliquam fermentum augue. Praesent sed efficitur metus. Phasellus accumsan, velit vel ornare auctor, nisi diam condimentum risus, sit amet ultricies est lacus vitae lectus. Etiam mattis lectus eu nunc lobortis efficitur. Nunc dui mauris, iaculis vitae dignissim in, ullamcorper vel odio. Sed gravida enim eu ex scelerisque, ut sagittis lacus ullamcorper. Fusce aliquet maximus lorem laoreet posuere. Nam tristique nisi ullamcorper felis tempus pulvinar.
</div>
```

Comment: I made mistake in my explanation (sorry for bad english). My sections are 100vh, and I have this image positoned on the bottom of the section, like on that picture. But, on different devices heights (1024x768, 1200x800) my image go bellow section or above, but I want to be like on that image - on same place on every device height. So I need help with that if you understand me.

Comment: Please post your html and css

Comment: This is my code:

.section-6-image-1 img {
 position: relative;
 right: 260px;
 top: 105px;
}

and image is on the bottom of the section. But, on different screen size (different screen heights), image go down/above place where I would like to stay - on the edge of section like on picture i posted.

I used position absolute but it was same..

Comment: It would be easier for me to help you if you can replicate your issue in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)